# How to extract pages when ranges repeat

Tags: page-numbering, dvips

I'm working on a book in which page numbers (`\count0`) repeat.
I have 24 pages of front matter numbered in roman numerals, about 800 pages of main text, and then another 400 pages of "Supplement" which are numbered `S1` to `S400`.  I want to extract pages 345 to 380 (a chapter) for review, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it using TeXlive on Debian Linux:

- If I use `dvips`, I get not only pages 345 to 380, but also pages S345 to S380.
- If I use `dvidvi` with option `-i (@1)345..(@1)380`, the resulting `.dvi` file is not convertible to PDF (conversion fails with an undefined identifier in the PostScript, might be `H.S`)

How can I extract the pages I want?  Is there a trick using `\count1` that might help?  I'd really like to avoid crawling `.aux` files and calculating absolute page numbers.

ETA: Doing it by hand by, say, using `xdvi` or Evince to get the page numbers, is not an option I really wish to pursue.  The point is to be able to get a previewed page range quickly---I'm mostly pulling these ranges from the chapter's table of contents.  Doing the arithmetic in my head every time would make me crazy!  (It's actually easier just to get the superfluous pages and then remove them using `pdftk`.  But I hope to do better.)

Comment: Is it an option to open the `dvi` file in Evince to find the absolute page numbers? Or just 345+24=369 to 380+24=404? So that would be `dvips -p =369 -l =404`. Or print to file from Evince with a page range. Or make a pdf and then extract the pages with `pdftk`. Or temporarily modify your supplement numbering in your LaTeX source.

Comment: I'd also use pdftk or similar as it uses the sheet count, not the page numbers

Comment: If you know how to do this "by hand" using `xdvi` etc then it should be scriptable. I have a similar issue, but without the repeating page numbers, where I need to extract various sections of the document. To do this I have automated `\label{...}` commands at appropriate places in the TeX file that, in effect, write custom markers to the aux file. I then have a python script read the aux file to find the page numbers and extract the pages that I need.